# systemd-resolved add option rotate Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, dns, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

I'm trying to add `options rotate` to my `resolv.conf` on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS upgrade

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

```
/etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

handled just by adding `options rotate` to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/body`

result as expected.

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.1.2.2
options rotate
```

18.04 LTS direct install

```
/etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53

systemctl disable systemd-resolved
systemctl stop systemd-resolved
apt install network-manager

add to /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
dns=default

add `options rotate` to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/body`

systemctl restart network-manager
systemctl restart resolvconf

/etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.1.2.2
options rotate
```

18.04 LTS upgrade from 16.04 LTS

Same steps as for 18.04 LTS and `resolv.conf` ends up with the same stub resolver 127.0.0.53,

After restart, file ends up with only `options rotate`

Is there a way to add `options rotate` using only the `systemd-resolved` method since this is what the Canonical devs insist on?

Is there a method (that I missed) that would help disable the `systemd-resolved` on the upgraded system?

It was upgraded from 16.04 LTS from a clean install, due to driver issues on the server.